# py-appscript filter with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, filter, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

I am trying to use the day field of a datetime property as a filter when selecting events from an iCal calendar.

The following doesn't seem to work (to select all events for the current date):

```
cal = app("iCal").calendars["myCalender"].get()
cDate = datetime.now()
cEvents = cal.events[its.start_date.day==cDate.day].get()
```

I get the result: `AttributeError: Unknown property, element or command: 'day'`

However, this works (for printing the days of any events)...

```
cal = app("iCal").calendars["myCalender"].get()
for cEvent in cal.events.get():
    print cEvent.start_date.get().day
```

Comment: Where does the `its` object from the first example come from?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
cal.events[its.start_date.day==cDate.day].get()
```

checks `its.start_date.day==cDate.day` and returns `False` or `True`. As an index, this translates into `0` and `1` and takes one of the first two elements in the `cal.events` list. Is this what you want?

Comment: it's not, `its.start_date.day` is a special object from appscript, with redefined __eq__ check. It works as fields in SQLAlchemy.